# Java parametrized method return value type

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following code:

```
class ExtType extends MyType{};

class MyClass {
    MyType myField;

    public <T extends MyType> T foo(Class<T> clazz) {
        return (T)myField;
    }
}
```

Now I want to call `foo` method, I can do this two ways:

1 way:

```
(new MyClass()).foo(ExtType.class);
```

2 way:

```
(new MyClass()).<ExtType>foo(ExtType.class);
```

Interesting, that even the method is declared as parametrized, Eclipse doesn't issue
any warning on 1 call.

Here is my question, in first code snippet, which of `T`s is used in casting return value.
Is it a `T` from parameter or `T` from return value? Why if I don't explicitly specify return type (as in "1 way") no warning is issued?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally the parameter type is used but if there is a return type defined (like in way 2) the compiler would check that as well.

The return type declaration would be necessary if there's no parameter to get the type of `T` from, which then is called type inference. Thus you could even write:

```
public <T extends MyType> T foo() {
    return (T)myField;
}


ExtType t = (new MyClass()).foo();
```

In some cases you need to help the compiler and specify the type to be used thus getting code like `(new MyClass()).<ExtType>foo(ExtType.class);`. Note, however, that if you'd define different types, e.g. `(new MyClass()).<MyType>foo(ExtType.class);`, you'd get a compile time error, since the compiler now doesn't know which one is used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Am I right that in case `(new MyClass()).foo();` is called, no cast inside `foo()` will be performed, or more correctly, there will be a cast to `Object`?

Comment: @gasan the cast will still happen but the type of `T` will be inferred from the type of the variable you assign the returned value to.

Comment: @Tomas, well, actually I've checked it using this code:`public class GenericTest {

    static class MyType {}
    static class ExtType extends MyType{};

    static class MyClass {
        MyType myField = new MyType();

        public <T extends MyType> T foo() {
            return (T)myField;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExtType t = (new MyClass()).foo();
        System.out.println(t);
    }

}` and ClassCastException happens only on assigning `foo()` result to `t` and `foo()` execution itself runs without an exception. Which means no cast in `foo()`.

Comment: And, well, maybe another question. You told that sometimes you need to specify type-parameter for return value to help compiler to figure out returning type, in addition to specifying type-parameter of the parameter. Could you provide such cases where it's required?

Comment: @gasan No, if you define the type by specifying a parameter you don't have to define the return type as well. But if you don't and rely on type inference only nesting such methods might cause the compiler not to be able to infer the type (this might be fixed in newer compiler versions though).

Answer (score 1):

When you define 'T' in a function declaration, and you will also define what T type it holds and returns. In you case, you are passing parameter and expecting same return type and declared 'T' as extends ExtType. So, eclipse doesn't generate any warnings.